# Setting SteamVR Camera Target Eye before SteamVR installed in Unity

Tags: unity, camera, steam-vr

I'm writing a plugin that can be used in both VR and non-VR projects. I have a Camera that is used to display UI containing some game info on a secondary monitor. My problem is that when the end-user adds my plugin and then imports steam vr, this UI camera's Target Eye is set to "Both" by default.

I can't have any SteamVR code in my plugin. But I can't adjust Target eye property of the camera without it. I just want it so that the camera doesn't change when a user imports SteamVR. I want it to always render to the main display (target eye = none)

So just to clarify,

1. I have my plugin, written in a non-vr project with a standard Unity camera. There is no Target Eye setting for this standard camera.
2. User wants to use it in VR project, imports plugin into SteamVR Project
3. Camera used to render UI gets automatically converted (wrongly) into SteamVR camera
4. Defaults to Target Eye = Both
5. Need it to be Target Eye = None

At the moment to avoid users submitting countless bug reports, I have to provide warnings in like 6 places telling users to dig way into my built-in prefabs to adjust this setting manually if they use SteamVR. It's not easy for new Unity users, and I want to make adoption as easy as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that newer versions of unity added the targetStereoEye variable to the camera even when SteamVR is not installed. This means I can pre-set the target eye to my desired value before SteamVR is installed.

Just had to update Unity. It's now 2019.2.12 for reference.